# Unpacking of string literal in a list item is working but not working for string literal itself

Tags: python, string, list

I see in python below discrepancies when working with unpacking string literals. I am not getting why this works this way. Can someone help to understand?

String got unpacked with it is present in list item:
Example:

```
>>>mylist = ["ABC"]
>>>for a,b,c in mylist:
...  print(a)
...  print(b)
...  print(c)
...
```

Result:

```
A
B
C
```

But, string unpacking is not working when assigned to a variable
Example:

```
>>>mystring = "ABC"
>>>for a,b,c in mystring:
...  print(a)
...  print(b)
...  print(c)
...
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for a,b,c in mystring:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: `for..in` iterates over the argument and then `a,b,c` iterates over each value within it again…! `["ABC"]` is "twice iterable", just `"ABC"` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

because you use it inside a for loop it is unpacking it twice..

u should use:

```
a,c,b = 'ABC'
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

or:

```
for letter in 'ABC':
    print(letter)
```

both will print the same:

```
>>> A
>>> B
>>> C
```